# Fringe – What is the real name of the Ending Theme?

Tags: soundtrack

In the American science fiction TV series [***Fringe***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fringe_(TV_series)) (2008–2013), at the end of each episode when the final credits are shown, a beautiful 30-second-long piece is played which I found on YouTube where it is called *Fringe Ending Theme*:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqDUX9aAcrM

Is *Fringe Ending Theme* the correct real name of that piece? If not, what is the correct name?

I need its real name to find sheet music or midi for that piece for me to be able to play it myself. Unfortunately, I am unable to pick up music by ear, so I badly need music notation of that piece.

Comment: Hey I am not sure if you aware of an App called shazam, Try to download it and let it listen to the piece it will let you know what is the status of the song in details.

Answer (score 1):

The music was composed by Michael Giacchino. On the [soundtrack album](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WL0ICKW) this piece is called "End Title Theme"

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where I can get sheet music or midi for that track?

Comment: @YellowSky Try googling it

Comment: I tried googling it, still, I cannot find neither sheet music nor midi for it. Maybe you know where I get them?